# Shell script: redirect output

Tags: bash, shell

Our shell script contains the header

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

that causes the commands to also be listed. Instead of having to type

```
$ ./script.sh &> log.txt
```

I would like to add a command to this script that will log all following output (also) to a log file. How this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place this line at the start of your script:

```
# redirect stdout/stderr to a file
exec &> log.txt
```

---

**EDIT:** As per comments below:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# redirect stdout/stderr to a file and still show them on terminal
exec &> >(tee log.txt; exit)
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to replace the `#!/bin/bash -x` with `exec &> log.txt`? If yes, how is ensured /bin/bash is launched?

Comment: @ThomasS no you don't

Comment: Just after `#!/bin/bash -x` line insert `exec &> log.txt`

Comment: Would `exec 2>&1 | tee log.txt` do the same, but also continue printing?